# Can I define a class method for a certain objects?

Tags: c++, scripting

Let's say I have some class which has an empty method:

```
class Foo {
   private:
      Sprite spr;

   public:
      //...
      void onLeftClick();
};
```

Let's say this method will be called when I click LMB on the sprite. Now, I have, for example, two Foo objects:

```
Foo first;
Foo second;
```

The thing is that I would like to "do something" when I click on one of those sprites my Foo objects have, but I would like to code different "response" for EVERY certain object. For example, one object will display a text when its clicked, second one will play a sound, third will make sprite move to some position, then play a sound and then the sprite will return to its beginning position. That's much variety of things to do...

I know that probably what I need here is some scripting language like Lua, but right now I'm really not familiar with scripting. Is there a way to achieve what I'd like to do in C++ only?

Comment: No need for _scripting language_, inject lambda functions for specific instances of `Foo`.

Comment: Reading about lambda functions right now. I'll see if it'll work. Thanks!

Comment: Reading about `std::function` should help as well.

Comment: Possibly just use subclasses of `Foo`.

Comment: I think I didn't ask my question right. Let me correct myself. I meant: how to execute a certain code, individual for each instance, passed somehow to an object or method of Foo, after clicking on object's sprite? Let's say I have three instances of Foo. And I would like to pass three different code pieces to each instance, so they can be executed when I click LMB on each object's sprite.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ gave you the correct way to do what you want to do. Every `Foo` could store a lambda that it can call; every lambda can have different behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ways to do what you want, but for starters you can try something like this:

```
class sprite
{
    // Let's say the parameters are the coordinates of the click
    using click_handler_t = std::function<void(sprite&, int, int)>;
    click_handler_t  click_handler;

    std::string name;

public:
    sprite(const std::string& name) : name{name} {}

    const std::string& get_name() const { return name; }

    void set_click_handler(click_handler_t new_handler) {
        click_handler = new_handler;
    }

    void on_click(int x, int y) {
        click_handler(*this, x, y);
    }
};
```

Then when you create your sprite, you can add any sort of handler you like, as long as it's callable with a compatible signature. For example, with a lambda:

```
sprite s1{"Sprite1"};
s1.add_click_handler( [](sprite& s, int x, int y) {
    std::cout << "Sprite " << s.get_name() << "clicked at (" 
              << x << "," << y << ")\n"; 
});
```

or with a free function:

```
void sprite2_clicked(sprite& s, int x, int y)
{
    // Some other action here
}

sprite s2{"Sprite 2"};
s2.add_click_hander(sprite2_clicked);
```

---

This is in fact just a very very basic version of the idea of signals used by most GUI libraries. If you're going to do something like this, I'd suggest using a proper signals library like `boost::signals2` or `libsigc++` rather than rolling your own.

Comment: This is a little too restrictive in that it requires a specific signature for the on_click event.

Comment: @bku_drytt It does, but that's a standard pattern for signals used by GUI libraries. How would you suggest doing it differently?

Answer (score 0):

C++ is a static typed language. It means that all types are defined at the **compile time**.
An INSTANCE of an object happens in **execution time**.

So by nature, C++ is not designed for you to have methods for specific objects! The Tristan Brindle's answer is a very good way around in case you want to do something like this. In the "lower level" of the dynamic typed languages, something similar is happening. You can, for example have a map of functions so you can call `myInstance.callFuncion["myMethodX"]()`. You found a way to "dynamize" the number of methods of an object...  :-)